# conditional import with type alias

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, import

I want to use the a conditional import on this code:

```
import {client1, client2} from "clients";
import {client3} from "outsideModule";

type clients = client1 | client2;

class A{
 private c : client3 | clients;
 
 public foo(value: string): string{
   if(condition){
       return (this.c as clients).bar1(value);
   }
   return (this.c as client3).bar2(value);
 }

/// another functions.
}
```

instead of the above I want to do the first import(client 1+2) only if the condition is true and in this case the type clients will be undefined or any(It doesn't really matter).
So, how can I do that?

I tried to do import from inside the condition scope but that didn't work.

Comment: You can't dynamically/conditionally import type definitions -- TypeScript requires them to be known and fixed at compile time. If you don't want the side effects of importing "outsideModule" for some reason I would either try `import type {client3} from "outsideModule";` which will *only* import the type definition, not the actual class/value of `client3` (so when the TypeScript is converted to JS the import will be completely removed), or if that solution isn't sufficient I would remove the `client3` import completely and just use `(this.c as as any)`  instead.